# Using Stripe CLI to Delete Errant Custom Accounts through Terminal

Tags: stripe-payments

I will admit that I am not that savvy when it comes to Stripe and I'm just learning.
In the process of setting up our Connect Account we added some Custom Accounts that were rejected or restricted. I have been informed the only way of removing said accounts is via Stripe API.
I installed Stripe CLI on my Mac in hopes that this would be easy. All I get are errors. This is currently what I am using as code and the response I get as an error:

```
$ stripe accounts delete acct_1JDDIoQSOur1AOsw --live
This command will be executed on the account with the following details:
> Mode: Live
> Account Name: LocalGood2Go
Are you sure you want to perform the command: DELETE?
Enter 'yes' to confirm: yes
{
  "error": {
    "message": "This application is not authorized to delete this account.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Is it not possible to delete account through the CLI? If not then please advise how I can use the API.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Does the CLI key you're using have permission to access that module? See https://stripe.com/docs/keys#limit-access , you can access your key permissions through https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys

Comment: Yeah what @LW001 is probably the issue - you'll want to make sure the CLI restricted access key has write permissions for all connect resources

Comment: Yes! Brilliant! That's exactly what it is and I feel like an idiot! Why doesn't Stripe have people like you guys working for them...? Thanks again!